# CSSが適用されない。そもそも参照しているパスが違う。

Tags: html, css, next.js

やったこと：
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/static-site-generation-with-nextjs/
を参考に下記を行いました。

```
$ npx create-next-app my-static-nextjs-app
$ cd my-static-nextjs-app
```

この状態で下記を行いブラウザーでローカルホストにアクセスすると正常な画面が表示されました。

```
$ npm run dev
```

このあと、サーバーを止めて、

上記記事にある通り package.json の build に `next export` を足し下記のようにしました。

```
"build": "next build && next export"
```

そして下記を実行。

```
$ npm run build
```

そうすると下記エラーが出ました。

```
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
  Possible solutions:
    - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
    - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
    - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
    - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
  Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api
    at /プロジェクトフォルダ名/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:257:23
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/プロジェクトフォルダ名/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
```

ちょっとReactとNext.jsの経験両方ないので、意味がわかっていませんが、

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65487914/no-exportpathmap-found-in-next-config-js-generating-map-from-pages

を参考に

`index.js`から

`import Image from 'next/image'` の行と
`<Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />` の行を削除しました。

そして再度、

```
$ npm run build
```

すると成功したようで `out`フォルダが出来ていました。その中の `index.html` は下記です。（ホントは一行で書かれていますが、インデントしてあります）

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title>Create Next App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="next-head-count" content="5" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/120f2e2270820d49a21f.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/120f2e2270820d49a21f.css" data-n-g="" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/eb291d7de33c874d5a88.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/eb291d7de33c874d5a88.css" data-n-p="" /><noscript
        data-n-css=""></noscript>
    <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-a54b4f32bdc1ef890ddd.js"></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-ddd010a953737b6e3536.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-b97a0ed4f13ff8397343.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-4809d8b3f3ef3c100198.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-220ac94ca11b92b10e31.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-9e3d432ffbe84eebc970.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/xeIQbCWm-8qD3c9J2l-Ky/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="/_next/static/xeIQbCWm-8qD3c9J2l-Ky/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="__next">
        <div class="Home_container__1EcsU">
            <main class="Home_main__1x8gC">
                <h1 class="Home_title__3DjR7">Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a></h1>
                <p class="Home_description__17Z4F">Get started by editing
                    <!-- --> <code class="Home_code__axx2Y">pages/index.js</code>
                </p>
                <div class="Home_grid__2Ei2F"><a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" class="Home_card__2SdtB">
                        <h2>Documentation →</h2>
                        <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
                    </a><a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" class="Home_card__2SdtB">
                        <h2>Learn →</h2>
                        <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
                    </a><a href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples" class="Home_card__2SdtB">
                        <h2>Examples →</h2>
                        <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
                    </a><a
                        href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&amp;utm_medium=default-template&amp;utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                        class="Home_card__2SdtB">
                        <h2>Deploy →</h2>
                        <p>Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.</p>
                    </a></div>
            </main>
            <footer class="Home_footer__1WdhD"><a
                    href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&amp;utm_medium=default-template&amp;utm_campaign=create-next-app"
                    target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Powered by
                    <!-- --> <span class="Home_logo__1YbrH"></span>
                </a></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="__NEXT_DATA__"
        type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{}},"page":"/","query":{},"buildId":"xeIQbCWm-8qD3c9J2l-Ky","nextExport":true,"autoExport":true,"isFallback":false,"scriptLoader":[]}</script>
</body>

</html>
```

ブラウザでアクセスすると添付画像のようにCSSがあたっていません。

[image]

`out/_next/static/css/120f2e2270820d49a21f.css`
とファイルは存在していますが、`index.html`は
`/_next/static/css/120f2e2270820d49a21f.css` を参照しにいっているようです。
つまり `out` フォルダの記載が `index.html` に足りません（早い話が参照しているパスが違います）。

どうすれば、`index.html`の`href` は `out` フォルダを参照できるようになりますか？（そのようなindex.htmlが生成されますか？）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

アクセスしているのは、`http://{host name}/out/index.html`ではなく、`http://{host name}/index.js`ですがあっていますか？
ルートがout/になっていますので、ホスティング先をout/にするかプレフィックスでパスが合うように調整したほうがいいと思います。

[Next.jsで静的HTMLエクスポートしたアプリをローカルで確認する方法](https://qiita.com/Nossa/items/bdc6a9705e89ea8fc250)
[Generated static files html files have wrong assets paths - Issues #8158 -  vercel/next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8158#issuecomment-779206290)

Comment: qiitaにあるサーバーを立てて解決する方法で試してみたところ、CSSが読み込まれました。ご回答の内容と、Githubのイシューのやりとりをみるかぎり、このパスはなにかしらのサーバーのドキュメントルート等に配置したときにうまく機能するように書かれてあり、単純にローカルでファイルにブラウザで直アクセスするとうまくいかない設計になっているようですね。